# Dir.entries(directory).reject{|f| [".", "..", "images", ".zip"].include? f}

Tags: ruby, dir

```
  dirs=Dir.entries(directory).reject{|f| [".", "..", "images", ".zip"].include? f}
```

I need to avoid including a zip file in "dirs" that is in "directory", this above isnt right, 
What is the correct syntax if I dont know the name of the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `Dir.entries(directory).reject { |f| f =~ /\.$|images|\.zip/ }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir.entries(directory).reject{|f| [".", "..", "images"].include? f}.reject{|f|f=~%r(\.(?i:)(?:zip)$)}
```

can this be done any better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in your reject call:

```
Dir.entries(directory).reject {|f| /\A(\.\.?|images|.*\.zip)\Z =~ f}
```

It's a little uglier, but it lets you use wildcard matching.  Hope that helps!